# Querying revenue by percentile in googlesql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to group companies and their revenues by percentiles (>90% as Top, 50-90% as middle, < 50% as bottom, in googlesql.

```
Table format for revenue_table:

|company | product | revenue |
------------------------------
```

I'm trying out doing a cross join to split these companies up:

```
SELECT 
  company,
  SUM(revenue) as revenue,
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(revenue) > Percentile90_Max THEN "Top"
    WHEN SUM(revenue) >= Percentile50_Max THEN "Middle"
    ELSE "Bottom"
  END as percentile_section,
  Percentile50_Max,
  Percentile90_Max,
FROM revenue_table
CROSS JOIN  
  (SELECT 
     APPROX_QUANTILES(revenue,100)[offset(50)] As Percentile50_Max,
     APPROX_QUANTILES(revenue,100)[offset(90)] As Percentile90_Max
   FROM 
     (SELECT 
        company,
        SUM(revenue) as revenue
      FROM revenue_table
      GROUP BY 1
     )
  )
GROUP BY 1,4,5
Order by 2 desc
```

The code above currently works, but gets broken once I change my main select statement to:

```
SELECT 
  company,
  --SUM(revenue) as revenue,
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(revenue) > Percentile90_Max THEN "Top"
    WHEN SUM(revenue) >= Percentile50_Max THEN "Middle"
    ELSE "Bottom"
  END as percentile_section,
  --Percentile50_Max,
  --Percentile90_Max,
  ... same code here
  GROUP BY 1
```

Ideally my end result should just be Company + percentile_section.

How should I do this without doing another subquery? Or is subquery really the only way to go in terms of querying efficiency?

Thank you!

Comment: You said it "gets broken", what error message did you receive?

Comment: @ggordon "SELECT list expression references column Percentile90_Max which is neither grouped nor aggregated"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to calculate the quantiles as part of the aggregation, so no subquery should be necessary:

```
SELECT company, SUM(revenue) as revenue,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(revenue) > (APPROX_QUANTILES(SUM(revenue), 100) OVER ())[offset(90)] THEN 'Top'
             WHEN SUM(revenue) >= (APPROX_QUANTILES(SUM(revenue), 100) OVER ())[offset(50)] THEN 'Middle'
             ELSE 'Bottom'
        END) as percentile_section
FROM revenue_table
GROUP BY 1
Order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Hi, by this you mean editting the GROUP BY to be "GROUP BY 1,3?

I will get this error: Column 3 contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY

Comment: @lyk . . . `group by 1`.

Comment: thanks! I just realized i might have missed out an additional information, which is the "product" column in revenue_table, hence I was trying to do it by cross join to get the correct percentile